# ¿Como puedo meter un onClick sobre un icono de react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Tengo esta función que muestra un rating con una valoración inicial con los iconos de material-icon de react  y quiero meterle la funcionalidad para poder clickar sobre ellos y que sea como un star-rating, es decir, que clique cuatro estrellas y se ponga cuatro estrellas.
¿Alguién sabría como hacerlo?

```
  const Rating = (props) => {
      const { value } = props;
    
      const ratingArr = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1].fill(0, value);
    
      return (
          <div className="Rating">
            {ratingArr.map((rating) => (rating ? <StarIcon /> : <StarOutlineIcon />))}
          </div>
      );
    };

    function MyComponent(valoracion_inicial){
      // Catch Rating value
      const handleRating = (rate: number) => {
        <Rating value={rate} />
        // other logic
      }

      return (
        <div className="App">
          <Rating value={valoracion_inicial} onClick={handleRating}  />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Comment: En javascript hay un plugin que es el `starrr.js`; lo importas en react en el index.html y ya solo haces la lógica en el componente.

Comment: Como importo el plugging en react, al importarlo me da problemas en su ejecución

Comment: Si lo haz metido en el index.html que tiene el react?

Comment: he metido la referencia al starrr.js en el index.html del react pero me da problemas de carga al cargar la página